# Please harshly judge my C++ Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: c++, rock-paper-scissors

My friend is taking a C++ course and it inspired me to write my own version of the "Rock, Paper, Scissors" assignment he was given in order to help ease me back into coding. I don't have any people other than said friend that can offer input on it, so I was hoping y'all could give me some.

I am prepared for harsh criticism.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>

void printLine (std::string text)
{
    std::cout << text + '\n';
    return;
}

//Allows for easy creation and output of menu/text boxes
class TextBox
{
    std::string title;

    std::string footer;

    std::string banner;

    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    bool numbered;

    bool hasFooter;

    bool built;

    bool reRender;

    void makeBanner ()
    {

        std::string newBanner;

        newBanner = "**";

        int lineLength = getLineLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
        {
            newBanner = newBanner + "*";
        }

        banner = newBanner;

        return;
    }

    int getLineLength ()
    {
        int longestString = title.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].size() > longestString)
            {
                longestString = lines[i].size();
            }
        }

        if (hasFooter && (longestString < footer.size()))
        {
            longestString = footer.size();
        }

        return longestString;
    }

    void renderLines ()
    {
        int lineLength = getLineLength() - 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
        {
            int lineLengthDifference = lineLength - lines[i].size();

            for (int x = 0; x < lineLengthDifference; x++)
            {
                lines[i] = lines[i] + ' ';
            }

            lines[i] = '*' + lines[i] + '*';
        }

        return;
    }

    void buildTextBox ()
    {
        if (numbered)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
            {
                lines[i] = "[" + std::to_string(i) + "] - " + lines[i];
            }
        }

        makeBanner();

        int lineLength = getLineLength();

        int lineLengthDifference = lineLength - title.size();

        int leftSpacing, rightSpacing;

        leftSpacing = rightSpacing = lineLengthDifference / 2;

        if ((lineLengthDifference % 2) > 0) {
            rightSpacing++;
        }

        std::string leftPadding = "*";
        std::string rightPadding = "*";

        //set left padding
        for (int i = 0; i < leftSpacing; i++)
        {
            leftPadding = leftPadding + ' ';
        }

        //set right padding
        for (int i = 0; i < rightSpacing; i++)
        {
            rightPadding = ' ' + rightPadding;
        }

        //center title in *
        title = leftPadding + title + rightPadding;

        //render lines
        renderLines();

        if (hasFooter)
        {
            int lineLength = getLineLength() - 2;

            int lineLengthDifference = lineLength - footer.size();

            int leftSpacing, rightSpacing;

            leftSpacing = rightSpacing = lineLengthDifference / 2;

            if ((lineLengthDifference % 2) > 0) {
                rightSpacing++;
            }

            std::string leftPadding = "*";
            std::string rightPadding = "*";

            //set left padding
            for (int i = 0; i < leftSpacing; i++)
            {
                leftPadding = leftPadding + ' ';
            }

            //set right padding
            for (int i = 0; i < rightSpacing; i++)
            {
                rightPadding = ' ' + rightPadding;
            }

            //center footer in *
            footer = leftPadding + footer + rightPadding;
        }

        built = true;

        return;
    }

    public:

    TextBox ()
    {
        reset();

        return;
    }

    void resetLines ()
    {
        lines.clear();

        reRender = true;

        return;
    }

    void reset ()
    {
        title = "No Title Set";
        footer = "";
        hasFooter = false;
        numbered = false;
        built = false;
        reRender = false;

        return;
    }

    void isNumbered (bool changed)
    {
        numbered = changed;
        return;
    }

    bool isNumbered ()
    {
        return numbered;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> getLines ()
    {
        return lines;
    }

    void setTitle (std::string newTitle)
    {
        title = newTitle;
        return;
    }

    void setFooter (std::string newFooter)
    {
        hasFooter = true;

        footer = newFooter;

        return;
    }

    void addLine (std::string line)
    {
        lines.push_back(line);

        return;
    }

    void print ()
    {
        if (!built)
        {
            buildTextBox();
        }

        if (reRender)
        {
            renderLines();
        }

        printLine(banner);
        printLine(title);
        printLine(banner);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
        {
            printLine(lines[i]);
        }

        printLine(banner);

        if (hasFooter)
        {
            printLine(footer);
            printLine(banner);
        }

        return;
    }
};

TextBox buildMainMenu ()
{
    //instantiate a new TextBox
    TextBox textBox;

    //tell the text box to number the lines
    textBox.isNumbered(true);

    //set title of the text box
    textBox.setTitle("You must choose a sign with which to attack your opponent.");

    //add lines to the text box
    textBox.addLine("Rock. This sign defeats scissors, but will lose against paper.");
    textBox.addLine("Paper. Paper will defeat rock, Scissors, however, will beat it handily.");
    textBox.addLine("Scissors. Scissors defeats paper, but stands no chance against rock.");

    //add a footer to the text box
    textBox.setFooter("Which symbol will you carry into battle?");

    return textBox;
}

TextBox buildContinueMenu ()
{
    //instantiate a new TextBox
    TextBox textBox;

    //set title of the text box
    textBox.setTitle("Results");

    textBox.setFooter("Would you like to play again? [0] - Yes / [1] - No");

    return textBox;
}

TextBox buildThankYouBox ()
{
    TextBox textBox;

    textBox.setTitle("Thanks for playing!");

    textBox.addLine("Written By:");

    textBox.addLine("Tim Andrus");

    return textBox;
}

int getAiAttack ()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    int attack = std::rand() % 3;

    return attack;
}

void calculateWinner (int playerAttack, int &aiAttack, int &result)
{
    //input
    /****************
     * 0 = rock     *
     * 1 = paper    *
     * 2 = scissors *
     ****************/

    //output
    /****************
     * 0 = tie      *
     * 1 = win      *
     * 2 = loss     *
     ****************/

    aiAttack = getAiAttack();

    //not a tie
    if (playerAttack != aiAttack)
    {
        //player win conditions
        if (
            //player rock : ai scissors = win
            (playerAttack == 0 && aiAttack == 2) ||
            //player paper : ai rock = win
            (playerAttack == 1 && aiAttack == 0) ||
            //player scissors : ai paper = win
            (playerAttack == 2 && aiAttack == 1)
        ) {

        result = 1;

        //player loss
        } else {

            result = 2;

        }
    }

    return;
}

std::string getAttackText (int attackValue)
{
    std::string text = "";

    switch (attackValue)
    {
        case 0:
            text = "rock";
            break;

        case 1:
            text = "paper";
            break;

        case 2:
            text = "scissors";
            break;
    }

    return text;
}

std::string getResultText (int resultValue)
{
    std::string text = "";

    switch (resultValue)
    {
        case 0:
            text = "tied";
            break;

        case 1:
            text = "won";
            break;

        case 2:
            text = "lost";
            break;
    }

    return text;
}

int main()
{
    TextBox mainMenu = buildMainMenu();

    TextBox continueMenu = buildContinueMenu();

    TextBox thankYou = buildThankYouBox();

    bool continueGame = true;

    bool continueInputIsValid = false;

    int playerAttack = 0;

    int aiAttack = 0;

    int result = 0;

    int playerContinue = 0;

    std::string playerAttackText = "";

    std::string aiAttackText = "";

    std::string resultText = "";

    do 
    {
        mainMenu.print();

        std::cin >> playerAttack;

        //check if attack is 0 - 2
        if (!((playerAttack >= 0) && (playerAttack <= 2)) || std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        calculateWinner(playerAttack, aiAttack, result);

        playerAttackText = getAttackText(playerAttack);

        aiAttackText = getAttackText(aiAttack);

        resultText = getResultText(result);

        continueMenu.addLine("You " + resultText + "!");
        continueMenu.addLine("You chose " + playerAttackText + ".");
        continueMenu.addLine("Your opponent chose " + aiAttackText + ".");

        do
        {
            continueMenu.print();

            std::cin >> playerContinue;

            if (!((playerContinue >= 0) && (playerContinue <= 1)) || std::cin.fail())
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                continue;
            }

            continueInputIsValid = true;

            //player chose not to play agian
            if (playerContinue != 0)
            {
                continueGame = false;
            }

        } while (!continueInputIsValid);

        continueMenu.resetLines();

    } while (continueGame);

    thankYou.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks double spaced, I can hardly fit any meaningful code on my laptop screen at once.

Answer (score 12):

There's good news and bad news. The good news is that it looks fairly complete. The bad news is that it's overly long, hard to read, lacking in consistency, and doesn't make sense in a lot of places.

I don't know what guideline you're using with regards to newlines, but this looks like you're using way too much of it:

```
makeBanner();

int lineLength = getLineLength();

int lineLengthDifference = lineLength - title.size();

int leftSpacing, rightSpacing;

leftSpacing = rightSpacing = lineLengthDifference / 2;
```

Those really don't need an extra line between them.

```
TextBox mainMenu = buildMainMenu();

TextBox continueMenu = buildContinueMenu();

TextBox thankYou = buildThankYouBox();

bool continueGame = true;

bool continueInputIsValid = false;

int playerAttack = 0;

int aiAttack = 0;

int result = 0;

int playerContinue = 0;

std::string playerAttackText = "";

std::string aiAttackText = "";

std::string resultText = "";
```

Those definitely don't need blank lines between them. No wonder your code is 502 lines. If you have two different blocks, I can understand why you'd separate them with a new line. After all, they're cheap and easily used as a separator. But you're not using them as a separator.

The following alternative for your last block would still use much whitespace, but it would at least make more sense:

```
TextBox mainMenu = buildMainMenu();
TextBox continueMenu = buildContinueMenu();
TextBox thankYou = buildThankYouBox();

bool continueGame = true;
bool continueInputIsValid = false;

int playerAttack = 0;
int aiAttack = 0;
int result = 0;
int playerContinue = 0;

std::string playerAttackText = "";
std::string aiAttackText = "";
std::string resultText = "";
```

See? Extra newlines can be useful, but use them too much and your code will look like a tangled mess.

You keep talking about an AI in your code. There is no AI. An AI is a form of intelligence, something capable of learning or problem solving. Something vaguely resembling human behaviour. Rock-Paper-Scissors is simply too simple to qualify for that. Especially if you're looking at how your program determines its move:

```
int getAiAttack ()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    int attack = std::rand() % 3;
    return attack;
}
```

It's a pseudo-random attack. No perception, no learning, no intelligence. By the way, you shouldn't be re-seeding the `srand` function here. Do that once, at the start of your program. While it may look to you that the current solution will increase the randomness, it will actually decrease it. Try playing 3 sets of 3 (restart the program after every set) with your current solution and with the seed moved and notice the difference.

You got a good start with your textboxes, but their current usage is cumbersome.

Your logic boils down to:

```
do 
{
    //menu & user input
    //validate user input
    //calculate winner
    //set texts
    //more text

    do
    {
        //more user input
        //validate more user input

        //convert validation result

    } while (!continueInputIsValid);
    //reset
} while (continueGame);
```

Also rather cumbersome, but not bad for a beginner. Your choice of how to set-up menus is impacting your programming style though. Try to rebuild the functions so, that lines like

```
    continueMenu.addLine("You " + resultText + "!");
    continueMenu.addLine("You chose " + playerAttackText + ".");
    continueMenu.addLine("Your opponent chose " + aiAttackText + ".");
```

are either taken care of by the functions returning those values (so no intermediate variables are required), or handled by a new function handling it all at once. Perhaps that function is going to need other functions (in OO design: methods), but it doesn't belong here immediately in the loop.

You also have a lot of odd text-to-string conversions going on:

```
//player rock : ai scissors = win
(playerAttack == 0 && aiAttack == 2)

result = 1;

    case 0:
        text = "rock";

    case 0:
        text = "tied";
```

Have you considered using [Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536024/1014587) instead? That would improve the readability and ease-of-programming a lot.

Your code is at this in-between stage, between straight programming and object-oriented. Create a Game class, a Player class (with a Player1 and Computer or Player1 and Player2 instance) and you can almost copy piece by piece from your current program to your new program. Yet it would look a lot cleaner, especially since this allows you to easily split-up your code. `Player.h`, `Player.c`, `Textbox.h`, `Textbox.c`, `Game.h`, `Game.c` and a main file to combine it all in.

Once you've done that, you'll notice it's also easier to modify the current code to any other simple game. Number guessing, hangman, perhaps even tic-tac-toe.

Oh, as a side-note: there's a typo in your comment here:

```
//player chose not to play agian
                             ^
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer focuses on the text box functionality.

## Review

> ```
> std::string footer;
> bool hasFooter;
> ```

Use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) instead:

```
std::optional<std::string> footer;
```

> ```
> void printLine (std::string text)
> {
>     std::cout << text + '\n';
>     return;
> }
> ```

Consider using `std::string_view` and stream the `\n` separately to avoid allocations.  The `return` can also be elided in `void` functions:

```
void print_line(std::string_view text)
{
    std::cout << text << '\n';
}
```

In fact, I don't think you need this function at all.

> ```
> void makeBanner ()
> {
>
>     std::string newBanner;
>
>     newBanner = "**";
>
>     int lineLength = getLineLength();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
>     {
>         newBanner = newBanner + "*";
>     }
>
>     banner = newBanner;
>
>     return;
> }
> ```

This function is too complex.  Use the `(count, character)` constructor of `std::string`.  Use `std::size_t` for line lengths.  It is also more readable to make it a free function and return the string instead of modifying in place:

```
std::string make_banner(std::size_t line_length)
{
    return std::string(line_length + 2, '*');
}
```

> ```
> int getLineLength ()
> {
>     int longestString = title.size();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
>     {
>         if (lines[i].size() > longestString)
>         {
>             longestString = lines[i].size();
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (hasFooter && (longestString < footer.size()))
>     {
>         longestString = footer.size();
>     }
>
>     return longestString;
> }
> ```

Add `const` to the function.  You can use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) here:

```
std::size_t max_length() const
{
    auto result = title.size();
    if (!lines.empty()) {
        auto it = std::max_element(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
                                   [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
                                       return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
                                   });
        result = std::max(result, it->size());
    }
    if (footer) {
        result = std::max(result, footer->size());
    }
}
```

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> getLines ()
> {
>     return lines;
> }
> ```

Use `const &` to prevent copying:

```
const auto& get_lines() const
{
    return lines;
}
```

## Redesign

Here is my version of the text box functionality:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

namespace detail {
    template <typename RanIt>
    std::size_t max_length(RanIt first, RanIt last)
    {
        auto it = std::max_element(
            first, last,
            [](std::string_view lhs, std::string_view rhs) {
                return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
            }
        );
        return it == last ? 0 : it->size();
    }
}

class TextBox {
public:
    template <typename RanIt>
    explicit TextBox(RanIt first, RanIt last)
    {
        lines.reserve(last - first + 2);

        auto length = detail::max_length(first, last);

        lines.emplace_back(length + 2, '*');
        std::transform(
            first, last,
            std::back_inserter(lines),
            [&](std::string_view sv) {
                auto padding = length - sv.size();
                return '*' + std::string(sv) + std::string(padding, ' ') + '*';
            }
        );
        lines.emplace_back(length + 2, '*');
    }

    const auto& rendered_lines() const
    {
        return lines;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
};
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tflCxnflQ6k4Y1V0))

Some notes:

- I opted for an immutable design.  The text box is built once, and the lines aren't modified.  This makes code easier to reason about.
- No reuse of variables (as you do with `lines` in your version).
- Instead of storing the original content, I rendered once and stored the result only.
- More simplistic — features such as titles, footers, etc. are omitted.